# Restricting image hot-linking with G-WAN

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking, g-wan

I want to serve static galleries, and I would like to know if G-WAN can restrict hot-linking to specified files?

Restricting image hot-linking would be good, but what I really want to know if there is possibility to disallow hot-linking images but allow hot-linking images that name ends with '_thumb' (thumbnails)?

```
if image_name_wo_ext end with '_thumb':
    allow image hot-linking
else:
    disallow image hot-linking
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to proceed:

This is can be done with a G-WAN `"connection handler"` or with a MIME `"content-type handler"` if you want to restrict the check to *.gif or to *.png files:

```
 http_t *http = (http_t*)get_env(argv, HTTP_HEADERS);

 static char my_site[] = "www.my_site.com";
 if(strcmp(my_site, http->h_referer)) // not my site
 {
    char *request  = (char*)get_env(argv, REQUEST);

    if(strstr(request, "_thumb"))
       return 0; // 0: Close the client connection
 }

 return 255; // continue normally
```

Alternatively, you can redirect to another page or image instead of just closing the connection:

```
    char szURI[] = "http://another-place.org";
    xbuf_t *reply = get_reply(argv);
    xbuf_xcat(reply,
              "<html><head><title>Redirect</title></head>"
              "<body>Click <a href=\"%s\">here</a>.</body></html>",
                    szURI);

    // set the HTTP reply code accordingly
    int *pHTTP_status = (int*)get_env(argv, HTTP_CODE);
    if(pHTTP_status)
       *pHTTP_status = 301; // 301:'moved permanently'

    // 2: Send a server reply based on a reply buffer/HTTP status code
    return 2;
```